# probability of selected cards consists the digits $1,2,3$

Tags: probability

> $K$ identification cards consists of $3$ digits selected from $10$ digits.Find the probability that the randomly selected cards contains  the digits $1,2$ and $3$

What i try:

we have to select $3$ Digits from $0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9$

Which can be done by $\displaystyle \binom{10}{3}$

And selected cards consists of digits $1,2$ and $3$. Which can be done by $1$ ways

So required probability $$\frac{1}{\binom{10}{3}}$$

But answer given as different.

Whats wrong with my reasoning. Help me please How do i solve it. Thanks

Comment: "*but answer given as different*"  What was the supposed given answer?  If you tell us that, then we can probably tell what the intended interpretation of the question was and whether or not there was an error in either your copying of the problem, the writing of the problem, or what...

Answer (score 0):

Assumption: any 3 digit number is possible,

You need to take into account the fact that $K$ is finite.  Assume all combinations are possible so $K=1000$.  In that case there are 6 cards $(123,132,213,231,312,321)$ so that the probability is $\frac{6}{1000}$.

Comment: This makes a rather heavy assumption that digits may be repeated in the ID's.  Granted, it is an equally heavy assumption that digits may not be repeated which the OP had made.  I would hold off on stating the answer with such confidence until the question is clarified or at least include what your assumptions are when solving the problem.

Comment: @JMoravitz Answer edited, although it seems unnecessarily